# Why is iso-octane different from other iso-s?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

While learning nomenclature of organic compounds I found the common  names to be a bit difficult to learn than the IUPAC ones. One of these common name stuff is the iso-,neo-, sec-, etc. So I searched for the ways to differentiate between these on the YouTube and found [this video](https://youtu.be/UPr8Z9SRnL0) (note that the anchor of the video uses hindi for communication so it might not be intelligible to most people here). To summarize what the anchor said:

> **Prefix-iso**: is used when all carbon atoms **except one** form a continuous chain.
>
> $$\mathcal {OR}$$
>
> They have a structure like this:
> [image: General Structure for iso- compounds and an example]

Now in the same video the anchor says that iso-octane is an exception to this rule, as it has the following shape:
[image: Iso-octane structure]

Before this came in the video I formed the view that these are just the ways of naming compounds with similar structure but now I think that that isn't the case. So:

- Why iso-octane has shape different than the other iso-s?

The anchor says that the structure of iso-octane was determined experimentally. This implies that there is some way to identify these compounds without knowing their structures beforehand so:

- How do we know that whether some given compound is iso-, neo-, etc?
- What might be the most general guidance for using iso-, neo-, sec- and tert- prefixes?

Comment: Do not try to learn chemistry from youtube videos of questionable background.

Comment: "secondary" and "tertiary" (+"primary", "quarternary") are clearly defined (by IUPAC) structural descriptors. "iso" and "neo" are not.

Comment: @Karl thanks for the suggestion. Actually this was the first time I watched a video from that channel and thought that it might be a legitimate one given that there are 100k+ subscribers. Though you are right and I do try to avoid such things but for now I wasn't able to find any other resources online so I had to reside for that video.

Comment: This would be one that is reasonably reputable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkane#Nomenclature

Comment: Looks like a slang term that got commonly recognized.  It's definitely unpleasant to the eye, much like $`` \mathrm{C} 0{}_{2} ".$

Answer (score 18):

The usage of non-standard prefixes such as "iso" has never been defined with hard, unambiguous rules such as those in the IUPAC recommendations. Instead, their usage has often more been "by convention". In *Organic Chemistry* (1st ed.) by Clayden et al., the authors write (p 315):

> Strictly speaking, if the standard meaning of ‘iso’ is followed, the name isooctane should be reserved for the isomer 2-methylheptane. However, 2,2,4-trimethylpentane is by far the most important isomer of octane and so, historically, it has been assigned this name.

(This phrase is also found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,2,4-Trimethylpentane), where it is copied wholesale without any indication that it's a direct quote. Please don't do this in your work. Even if you provide a citation, you should either paraphrase the information, or clearly indicate that it's a quote, e.g. by enclosing it in quotation marks.)

Comment: If I remember right from ~25 years ago quoting my chemistry teacher "Iso-" [equal] indicates a mixture of carb-molecules where the longest chain is the name-giver .. as in iso-octane being an 8-carbon chain. .. Other possible molecules use side-chains of 1 or 2 carbons length.