# Is neo-octane possible and if yes, what is its structure?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons, isomers

I know iso-octane is an exception and is 2,2,4-Trimethylpentane which intuitively contains both iso and Neo groups. But then what is the structure of neo-octane or even is it possible?

Comment: It is no use making up prefixes for all isomers of higher alkanes. That said, what would you call a 2,2-dimethylhexane?

Comment: Neo-octane is not an accepted name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed "neo-octane" to begin with. If you look at [isomers of octane](https://www.docbrown.info/page06/isomers/isom-c8h18.htm), you will see 4 of them have [neo group](https://www.chem.ucla.edu/%7Eharding/IGOC/C/common_name.html) out of which 2,2,4-Trimethylpentane has been commonly referred to as iso-octane although it contains both iso- and neo- group. Even if we eliminate isomers containing iso- group, we are left with [2,2-dimethylhexane](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2_2-Dimethylhexane) and [2,2,3,3-dimethylbutane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetramethylbutane). Which one will you consider "neo-octane"?

[These non-standard prefixes are not defined in IUPAC](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/127953/why-is-iso-octane-different-from-other-iso-s?rq=1), so it is better to define them with their standard IUPAC names to avoid ambiguity.